# NG2-Charts Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to use the basic example of NG2-Charts (http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

I copy pasted the HTML part

```
  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        [chartType]="barChartType"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
```

and the TypeScript part

```
  private barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
  };
  private barChartLabels: string[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  private barChartType: string = 'bar';
  private barChartLegend: boolean = true;

  private barChartData: any[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
    { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
  ];

  // events
  private chartClicked(e: any): void {
      console.log(e);
  }

  private chartHovered(e: any): void {
      console.log(e);
  }
```

I run `npm install ng2-charts --save`, `npm install chart.js --save` and `typings install dt~chart.js --save --global`

I also imported chart.js in my vendor.ts file

```
import 'chart.js';
```

My dependencies:

```
{
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.18",
    "chart.js": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  }
```

Here is the Error

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("iuminfooneoptionsTwo">
            <div style="display: block">
                <canvas baseChart [ERROR ->][datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLeg"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:34
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("          <div style="display: block">
                <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [ERROR ->][labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChart"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:60
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("lay: block">
                <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [ERROR ->][options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartH"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:86
Can't bind to 'legend' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("  <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [ERROR ->][legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:114
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("ets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [ERROR ->][chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:140 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("iuminfooneoptionsTwo">
            <div style="display: block">
                <canvas baseChart [ERROR ->][datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLeg"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:34
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("          <div style="display: block">
                <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [ERROR ->][labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChart"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:60
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("lay: block">
                <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [ERROR ->][options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartH"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:86
Can't bind to 'legend' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("  <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [ERROR ->][legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:114
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("ets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [ERROR ->][chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
"): PlayerprofileComponent@39:140
    at TemplateParser.parse (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:623:1), <anonymous>:133:19)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2103:1), <anonymous>:244:51)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2103:1), <anonymous>:167:83)
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at compile (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2103:1), <anonymous>:167:47)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:4105:1), <anonymous>:192:28)
    at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:4105:1), <anonymous>:85:43)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:4105:1), <anonymous>:451:57)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:4105:1), <anonymous>:225:37)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:4105:1), <anonymous>:125:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:4105:1), <anonymous>:357:35)
```

The NG2-Charts website says I need to include this in the HTML

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

But I think thats not correct because how would that statement work in a productive minified / built app? I also thought my webpack import statement would already take care of that? 
I googled around but sadly only found stuff for some Angular 2 Beta version on NG2 Charts.

Does anyone has an idea on how to fix that?

Thanks and Cheers, 
Raphael Hippe

Comment: Have you imported ChartsModule in your app.module.ts ?

Comment: No I haven't! That would make sense! But I can't find anything on the NG2-Charts website regarding that module. How would the import statement look like?

Comment: already imported ChartsModule in your app.module.ts  but still getting issue.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try importing ChartsModule in your app.module.ts like this-

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

imports: [
   .....
   ChartsModule
   .....
]
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks :) 
This should get added to the website (http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) so setting up instruction are more clear.

Comment: Is there a difference between from 'ng2-charts' vs 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts'? I tried both and neither one of them worked for me. I am using ng2-charts (1.6.0) and chart.js (2.7.2).

Comment: This shouldn't really matter I suppose?? I'm importing from `'ng2-charts'` and it works fine. Check if you're using submodules as _André Luiz_ is saying.

Comment: I dont think this works now,
try, 
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

Comment: import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
But it should be at the module where you imported the component that you want to show the chart on.

Comment: i have the same problem as him but I can't import the ChartsModule because I have ngChartsModule?

Comment: For `ng2-charts` version 3.1.2 and compatible `chartJs` version 3.4.0 I had to import `import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';` to make it work.

Answer (score 28):

I had the very same problem. I found on github that you just have to insert the ChartsModule in the submodule as well. First you add in `app.module.ts` and the, in my case, `reports.module.ts`.

Comment: I had the same problem as well! If you're only using the charts in `reports.module.ts`, you could loose the import in `app.module.ts`. Thanks

Comment: You are my Hero, it works like magic. Thanks a lot. I am using ionic 4 version and added import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts'; in tab1.modules.ts file and also added ChartsModule keyword in imports array. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know how different our projects are different structurally, but in my case, removing the import from the `app.module.ts` made the application crash.

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this problem. This answer shows the two places to import the ChartsModule and this saved my day.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem in angular 8

Comment: Just importing ChartsModule  at sub module level works, this is inline with other ngx-charts library by swimlane where we import NgxChartsModule

Comment: For me, it was enough only to add ChartsModule import to the Component (reports.module.ts) module!

Answer (score 20):

I'm working with ng2-charts + Angular 7 + Ionic 4, and I spent several hours searching for a solution. And this finally worked to me (after following the initial steps, of course, like installing ng2-charts and charts.js). Just import ChartsModule on the following files:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
...
imports: [ChartsModule]
```

**yourPage.module.ts**

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: YourPagePage }]),
    **ChartsModule**
  ]
})
```

I was trying to import it also in yourPage.page.ts, but the solution was to import it in yourPage.module.ts!

Try it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It worked for me. I spent a few days trying to understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You´re welcome, Pastor. Anyway, I came across the same problem these days and this my solution wasn´t enough to solve it. To solve it, I also needed to _export_ the ChartsModule in the **yourPage.module.ts** file. It means I needed to declare it inside the **exports** array too: exports: [ ... ChartsModule ...]

Comment: In Ionic and Angular projects works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

i'm working with `ng2-chart@3.0.0-rc.2`

looks like the property `chartType` is now called `type`

so it should look something like this:

```
    <canvas 
      style="display: block;background-color: #3a3939;" 
      width="600" 
      height="300" 
      id="canvas" 
      #myCanvas
      
      baseChart 
      [type]="lineChartType" 
      [datasets]="lineChartData" 
      [labels]="lineChartLabels" 
      [options]="mfChartOptions"
      [legend]="lineChartLegend">
    </canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your component is declared in another module other than `app.module.ts` you will simply do the following:

**`app.module.ts`**

```js
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

...

@NgModule({
   ...

   imports: [
      ...
      ChartsModule,
      ...
   ]
})
export class AppModule{ }
```

**`module-where-your-component-is-declared.module.ts`**

```js
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

...

@NgModule({
   declarations: [YourComponent],
   imports: [
      ...
      ChartsModule,
      ...
   ],
   ...
})
export class ModuleWhereYourComponentIsDeclared { }
```

Answer (score 3):

**The reason might be:** You are using Ng2Charts directly from your child components/module.

**Solutions:** You have to import the Ng2Charts on your parent module as well. (Import Ng2Charts [ng2-charts], to your parent and child module)

Happy fixing everyone.

Thank you.
Marjun Villegas

Comment: When using version 4.0 or above this doesn't work because you need to import a completely different module. You need to import NgChartsModule.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a Shared Module, you also need to export the ChartsModule from there, to make it available to all your components which use your Shared Module.

```
// Simplified module only showing what's important for ChartsModule
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [ChartsModule],
    exports: [ChartsModule]
})

export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SharedModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing the ChartsModule in App Module, import it in inside module where your are using. For example, home module (if using Charts in Home page).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was nothing to do with including `ChartsModule` in multiple modules or exporting it.

I had created a chart component that used `ng-chart` and then found I needed another version of it.  So I copied the component, renamed the class and template file, but forgot to update the `templateUrl` property in the `@Component` decorator.

Having two different components referencing the same template file gave the exact same error:

> Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

As soon as I changed the new component to use the correct HTML template, the error was resolved.

FYI, I reference `ChartsModule` as shown in @sanket's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40016855/4591974) in the module of my chart components <del>and the module of the page components that reference them</del> (so it's not needed in `AppModule`).

Answer (score 0):

ANGULAR 14

The current import now is:

```
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

// In your App's module:
imports: [
  NgChartsModule
]
```

[source](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular version 14, ng2-charts version 4, and a standalone component, then you have to import `NgChartsModule` in both `app.module.ts` and `your.component.ts` files.

your.component.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartConfiguration, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NgChartsModule],
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgChartsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to change how I import and a little change in my html file tag:

**chart.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@Component({
    selector: 'chart-balance',
    template: require('./templates/chart-balance.template'),
    styles: [`.chart {display: block; width: 100%;}`],
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ChartBalanceComponent {
    public barChartOptions:any = {
        scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    callback: label => `${label.toLocaleString()}`
                }
            }]
        }
    };
    public barChartLabels:string[] = ['2014', '2015', '2016'];
    public barChartType:string = 'bar';
    public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

    public barChartData:any[] = [
        {data: [32131, 3432, 543], label:'Test 1'},
        {data: [54353, 432, 768], label:'Test 2'}
    ];

    // events
    public chartClicked(e:any):void {
        console.log(e);
    }

    public chartHovered(e:any):void {
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

Here was another change I did:

> notice -- > base-chart class="chart" ...

**chart-balance.template**

```
<base-chart class="chart"
        [datasets]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        [chartType]="barChartType"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
```

**ng2-charts**

```
export * from './components/charts/charts';
declare var _default: {
    directives: any[][];
};
export default _default;
```

**charts**

```
import { OnDestroy, OnInit, OnChanges, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
export declare class BaseChartComponent implements OnDestroy, OnChanges, OnInit {
    static defaultColors: Array<number[]>;
    data: number[] | Array<number[]>;
    datasets: any[];
    labels: Array<any>;
    options: any;
    chartType: string;
    colors: Array<any>;
    legend: boolean;
    chartClick: EventEmitter<any>;
    chartHover: EventEmitter<any>;
    private ctx;
    private cvs;
    private parent;
    private chart;
    private initFlag;
    private element;
    constructor(element: ElementRef);
    ngOnInit(): any;
    ngOnChanges(): any;
    ngOnDestroy(): any;
    getChartBuilder(ctx: any): any;
    private refresh();
}
export interface Color {
    backgroundColor?: string | string[];
    borderWidth?: number | number[];
    borderColor?: string | string[];
    borderCapStyle?: string;
    borderDash?: number[];
    borderDashOffset?: number;
    borderJoinStyle?: string;
    pointBorderColor?: string | string[];
    pointBackgroundColor?: string | string[];
    pointBorderWidth?: number | number[];
    pointRadius?: number | number[];
    pointHoverRadius?: number | number[];
    pointHitRadius?: number | number[];
    pointHoverBackgroundColor?: string | string[];
    pointHoverBorderColor?: string | string[];
    pointHoverBorderWidth?: number | number[];
    pointStyle?: string | string[];
    hoverBackgroundColor?: string | string[];
    hoverBorderColor?: string | string[];
    hoverBorderWidth?: number;
}
export interface Colors extends Color {
    data?: number[];
    label?: string;
}
export declare const CHART_DIRECTIVES: Array<any>;
```