# Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm trying to use ng2-charts and run into an error that says the elements I'm using are incorrect.
I've tried a few answers on this site, but no luck:

[NG2-Charts Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016333/ng2-charts-cant-bind-to-datasets-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-canvas)

[ng2-charts - Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301229/ng2-charts-cant-bind-to-datasets-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-base-c)

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "four-item-horse-shoe-graph.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["four-item-horse-shoe-graph.component.css"],
    selector: "four-item-horse-shoe"
})

export class FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent {
    // Doughnut
    public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = ["Download Sales", "In-Store 
        Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    public doughnutChartData: number[] = [350, 450, 100];
    public doughnutChartType: string = "doughnut";

    // events
    public chartClicked(e: any): void {
        console.log(e);
    }

    public chartHovered(e: any): void {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div style="display: block">
<canvas baseChart
        [data]="doughnutChartData"
        [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
        [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
            'chart': 'npm:chart.js/src/chart.js',
        "ng2-charts": "node_modules/ng2-charts"
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        "ng2-charts": { main: "ng2-charts.js", defaultExtension: "js" }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { ChartsModule } from "ng2-charts/ng2-charts";

declare let jQuery: Object;

@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    CoreFeatureModule,
    LayoutModule,
    ChartsModule
```

ERROR:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("<div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [ERROR ->][data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutCh"): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@2:9
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
    <canvas baseChart
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [ERROR ->][labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="char"): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@3:9
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [ERROR ->][chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@4:9 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError {_nativeError: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("<d…} Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("<div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [ERROR ->][data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutCh"): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@2:9
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
    <canvas baseChart
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [ERROR ->][labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="char"): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@3:9
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [ERROR ->][chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@4:9
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1595:29) [<root>]
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1793:18) [<root>]
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11222:21) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27474:70) [<root>]
    at eval (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27357:64) [<root>]
    at Set.forEach (native) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27357:21) [<root>]
    at createResult (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27240:21) [<root>]
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43) [<root> => <root>]
    at http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:520:57 [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:418:35) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25) [<root>]
consoleError @ zone.js:405
_loop_1 @ zone.js:434
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:438
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:349
zone.js:407 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("<div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [ERROR ->][data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutCh"): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@2:9
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
    <canvas baseChart
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [ERROR ->][labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="char"): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@3:9
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [ERROR ->][chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@4:9
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("<div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [ERROR ->][data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutCh"): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@2:9
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
    <canvas baseChart
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [ERROR ->][labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="char"): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@3:9
Can't bind to 'chartType' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
            [data]="doughnutChartData"
            [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
            [ERROR ->][chartType]="doughnutChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="): FourItemHorseShoeGraphComponent@4:9
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1595:29) [<root>]
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1793:18) [<root>]
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11222:21) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27474:70) [<root>]
    at eval (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27357:64) [<root>]
    at Set.forEach (native) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27357:21) [<root>]
    at createResult (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27240:21) [<root>]
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43) [<root> => <root>]
    at http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:520:57 [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:418:35) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25) [<root>]
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1595:29) [<root>]
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1793:18) [<root>]
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:11222:21) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27474:70) [<root>]
    at eval (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27357:64) [<root>]
    at Set.forEach (native) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27357:21) [<root>]
    at createResult (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27240:21) [<root>]
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43) [<root> => <root>]
    at http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:520:57 [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:418:35) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25) [<root>]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:31) [<root>]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:471:17) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:520:17 [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:418:35) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:44444/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:349:25) [<root>]
consoleError @ zone.js:407
_loop_1 @ zone.js:434
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:438
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:349
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I needed to import the ChartModule in the module.ts file of the component that I wanted to use the chart in.  I originally only had it imported in app.module.ts.

Comment: have you done any other changes? I am having the exact same problem but your solution is not working for me.

Comment: NgChartsModule is improted from ng2-charts[3.0.0-rc] instead of ChartsModule, and its bringing another new error on the app when it loads : 
>
>      `TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Chart.register is not a function`

Answer (score 21):

Try using the attribute syntax for binding:

Instead of:

```
[data]="doughnutChartData"
```

Try:

```
attr.data="{{doughnutChartData}}"
```

I'm not certain if this will work in your case, but this has to do with what's a DOM property versus an attribute, and how Angular handles binding for both.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  That got rid of the errors, but now the graph isn't getting drawn.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not certain how canvas works when Angular gets involved, unfortunately.  Maybe there's an npm package or something?  Angular 4.2 should have new animations, if that helps.

Comment: Figured it out.  I had to import ChartModule in my current components module.ts file.

Comment: @ArtisanSamosa How did you do it my errors are gone but chart isn't showing?

Answer (score 3):

In the app.module.ts file, within the NgModule decorater there is an array called imports, mention ChartsModule in the imports array like this

> imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),**ChartsModule** ],

It helped me. It can be helpful to you as well

Comment: Editor unable to find ChartsModule, instead it gives suggestion to use 

import { NgChartsModule } from "ng2-charts";


On Adding it to imports of module.ts file, error thrown at browser console : 

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Chart.register is not a function
TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Chart.register is not a function

Answer (score 1):

> For Angular 7 or greater version use
>
> npm install ng2-charts@2.2.3
>
> --save npm install chart.js --save