# NG0303: Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

Tags: canvas, chart.js, pie-chart, angular11, ng2-charts

I did following steps:
npm install ng2-charts@next --save

> It installed
>
> ```
> "ng2-charts": "^3.0.0-rc.7"
> ```

npm install chart.js --save

> It installed
>
> ```
> chart.js": "^2.9.4",
> ```

npm install --save-dev ng2-charts-schematics

npm install

ng serve -o

> Angular version is 11.2
>
> ```
> "@angular/compiler": "11.2.2",
> "@angular/core": "11.2.2",
> "@angular/forms": "11.2.2",
> ```

When the parent component page loads, it throws these errors:

> ```
>   NG0303: Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
>     
>    NG0303: Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
>     
>    NG0303: Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
>     
>    NG0303: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
>     
>    NG0303: Can't bind to 'plugins' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
>     
>    NG0303: Can't bind to 'legend' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
> ```

What could have gone wrong? this is not working?
On expanding this alerts, :

> logUnknownPropertyError @ InteractionHandler.ts:10069
> elementPropertyInternal @ InteractionHandler.ts:9961
> ɵɵproperty @ InteractionHandler.ts:14700
> PieChartComponent_Template @ template.html:2
> executeTemplate @ InteractionHandler.ts:9545
> refreshView @ InteractionHandler.ts:9414
> refreshComponent @ InteractionHandler.ts:10580
> refreshChildComponents @ InteractionHandler.ts:9211
> refreshView @ InteractionHandler.ts:9464
> refreshComponent @ InteractionHandler.ts:10580
> refreshChildComponents @ InteractionHandler.ts:9211
> refreshView @ InteractionHandler.ts:9464
> refreshEmbeddedViews @ InteractionHandler.ts:10534
> refreshView @ InteractionHandler.ts:9438
> refreshComponent @ InteractionHandler.ts:10580
> refreshChildComponents @ InteractionHandler.ts:9211
> refreshView @ InteractionHandler.ts:9464
> refreshEmbeddedViews @ InteractionHandler.ts:10534
> refreshView @ InteractionHandler.ts:9438
> refreshEmbeddedViews @ InteractionHandler.ts:10534
> refreshView @ InteractionHandler.ts:9438
> refreshComponent @ InteractionHandler.ts:10580
> refreshChildComponents @ InteractionHandler.ts:9211
> refreshView @ InteractionHandler.ts:9464
> renderComponentOrTemplate @ InteractionHandler.ts:9528
> tickRootContext @ InteractionHandler.ts:10754
> detectChangesInRootView @ InteractionHandler.ts:10779
> detectChanges @ InteractionHandler.ts:22792
> tick @ InteractionHandler.ts:29516
> (anonymous) @ InteractionHandler.ts:29397
> ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:386
> onInvoke @ InteractionHandler.ts:28535
> ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:385
> Zone.run @ zone.js:143
> run @ InteractionHandler.ts:28419
> next @ InteractionHandler.ts:29396
> schedulerFn @ InteractionHandler.ts:25889
> __tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:265
> next @ Subscriber.ts:207
> _next @ Subscriber.ts:139
> next @ Subscriber.ts:99
> next @ superPropBase.js:70
> emit @ InteractionHandler.ts:25879
> checkStable @ InteractionHandler.ts:28472
> onHasTask @ InteractionHandler.ts:28552
> ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
> ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:462
> Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:284
> Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
> drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:601
> Promise.then (async)
> scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:584
> ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
> onScheduleTask @ zone.js:294
> ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:400
> Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:231
> Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:251
> scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:881
> resolvePromise @ zone.js:819
> (anonymous) @ zone.js:739
> webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
> (anonymous) @ layouts-admin-layout-admin-layout-module.js:1
> Show 20 more frames
> InteractionHandler.ts:10069

Pie chart html:

> <canvas baseChart
> [type]="'pie'"
> [datasets]="pieChartDatasets"
> [labels]="pieChartLabels"
> [options]="pieChartOptions"
> [plugins]="pieChartPlugins"
> [legend]="pieChartLegend">

Pie chart ts file

> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
> import { ChartType, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
> // import { SingleDataSet, Label, monkeyPatchChartJsLegend, monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip } from 'ng2-charts';
>
> @Component({
> selector: 'app-pie-chart',
> templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
> styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.css']
> })
>
> export class PieChartComponent {
>
> // Pie
> public pieChartOptions: ChartOptions<'pie'> = {
> responsive: false,
> };
> public pieChartLabels = [ [ 'Download', 'Sales' ], [ 'In', 'Store', 'Sales' ], 'Mail Sales' ];
> public pieChartDatasets = [ {
> data: [ 300, 500, 100 ]
> } ];
> public pieChartLegend = true;
> public pieChartPlugins = [];
> }

module.ts has these:

> import { PieChartComponent} from 'src/app/components/pie-chart/pie-chart.component';

> declarations: [
> PieChartComponent
> ]

Parent html file have
`<app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart>`

Please Suggest?
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/1459[Issue on official Github]

Comment: I have checked solution/suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903174/cant-bind-to-data-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-canvas 
>>But it throw another error mentioned in the comments

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Chart.register is not a function at ng-charts.module.ts:32

Answer (score 0):

You should not install the `next` branch of ng2-charts, that is an older version as the most recent one, also when using ng2-charts version 3.0 or above you need to make sure you have at least version 3.0 of Chart.js installed, it does not work with version 2.

Using `npm i chart.js` should not give you 2.9.4 as you claimed, it should install the latest version but to be sure you can just specify the latest versions for both:

```bash
npm i chart.js@3.8.2
npm i ng2-charts@3.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks @LeeLenalee , I deleted nodes_module and package-lock.json file, and re-installed these two libraries . Still getting these error > > `Error: ./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs 512:22-44
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)`

Comment: idk then what the issue is, can you reproduce it wit hstackblitz?

Comment: Thanks @LeeLenalee for suggesting that, I just replicated the error on stackblitz with same version numbers [chart.js@3.8.2 , ng2-charts@3.1.2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rzrqxu?file=package.json) > > >  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rzrqxu?embed=1&file=package.json