# After downgrading versions of chart.js and ng2-charts I can't bind any properties to canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, chart.js, ng2-charts

*Solutions that didn't work: [1 (SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40016333/11101156) and [2 (GitHub issue)](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/553)*

My first problem was version incompatibility between `ng2-charts` and `chart.js` so I ended up using [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66938929/11101156) and it worked (so now my `package.json` looks like this `"ng2-charts": "^2.4.3"` and `"chart.js": "^2.9.4"`).

But now another problem developed - I can't bind anything to the canvas inside `page.html` files:

[image]

- I have tried importing `ChartsModule` inside `mypage.module.ts` and also in `app.module.ts` without any changes.
- I have no errors on compiling - only errors I get are those inside `console.log` when I jump into my page.
- I have also tried this [solutio on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40016855/11101156) suggesting to add `'ng2-charts/ng2-charts'` inside the import. But still no changes.

### How can I bind properties to the canvas properly in `Angular` with `ng2-charts` library?

---

Html code for my page:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/home"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title> Trendy {{ device.name }}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid class="center">
      <canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="dataX"
        [labels]="dataY"
        [chartType]="lineChartType">
      </canvas>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Page module.ts code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { TableDeviceTrendsPageRoutingModule } from './table-device-trends-routing.module';

import { TableDeviceTrendsPage } from './table-device-trends.page';

import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    TableDeviceTrendsPageRoutingModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
  declarations: [TableDeviceTrendsPage]
})
export class TableDeviceTrendsPageModule {}
```

Comment: I just created a new ionic project and using "ng2-charts": "^2.4.3" and "chart.js": "^2.9.4", and it worked fine. Can you share a sample project for us to look at?

Comment: A simple restart did the trick at the end ... sorry for bringing this up so late.